# Left shift acting as right click

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, macros

If anybody is having the problem where when you press left shift it doesn't actually capitalize  anything and for some reason decides to right click instead, just check your keyboards like software. For example, I have a SteelSeries keyboard, and somehow by pressing f10 and shift at the same time while trying to learn code, it decided to save that as a macro on my shift key, allowing me to only right click with it. For like 30 minutes I was completed frustrated because every google search led me no where, but then I checked my SteelSeries software as a last ditch effort, and it had saved it as a macro. So i hope this helps anybody else who is just pissed off.

Comment: I do not think this is a general issue. No problem with Left Shift here (Lenovo, Macally, and LogiTech keyboards). I think your issue may be unique to your keyboard.

Comment: This site is not run like a forum, we need question and answers.  Can you remove the answer from above and post it as an answer